# How do I handle this unusual date time format in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a datetime format from an API that is formatted as so:

```
Thu, 17 Nov 2016 19:12:12 GMT
```

I am unsure how to format this in PHP to something that I can check for an hour difference. The problem is that this not one of the standard date time constant formats in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

The 3 letter day and GMT timezone in the end is what's mostly tripping me up here.

Comment: Both `strtotime()` and the `DateTime` class can parse this string into a timestamp.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php